# How can I reuse code for similar attributes with FactoryBot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

Say I've two models `Person` and `Company`, both are different models, however they both have one common attribute: `address`. If I were to use FactoryBot, I'd implement the respective factories as follows:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :person do
    # ...
    address { Faker::Address.street_address }
  end
end

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :company do
    # ...
    address { Faker::Address.street_address }
  end
end
```

Is there a way where I can define an `address generator` that I can call from anywhere inside factories?. For example:

```
# define reusable attribute
FactoryBot.define do
    attribute :address { Faker::Address.street_address }
end

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :person do
    # ...
    generate_attribute(:address)
  end
end

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :company do
    # ...
    generate_attribute(:address)
  end
end
```

Currently I can replicate this desired behaviour with `sequences`, but it seems they're not meant for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a function anywhere inside factories, you can create a spec helper and define you function there:

```
# AppSpecHelper
# spec/support/app_spec_helper
module AppSpecHelper
  def generate_attribute
    ...
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.include AppSpecHelper
end
```

In `rails_helper.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include AppSpecHelper
end
```

Comment: I'm getting undefined method `generate_attribute' for #<FactoryBot::SyntaxRunner:0x000000000920db00>

Comment: Doesn't seem like it can be done this way so simply. https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/issues/564

Answer (score 2):

I think you can specify a nil class for a factory which would allow you to have a common parent for those two factories:

```
factory :addressable, class: nil do
  address { Faker::Address.street_address }
end

factory :person, parent: :addressable do
  ...
end

factory :company, parent: :addressable do
  ...
end
```

Comment: oh that's clever. I think I can benefit from this approach using nil classes.

Answer (score 0):

A small addition to answer of @Shadwell

I believe, in newer versions `person` and `company` will try to use class of parent for initialization, which will result in `Addressable.new`. This can be avoided with `class` option to child factories:

```rb
# NOTE: class: nil is actually optional
factory :addressable, class: nil do
  address { Faker::Address.street_address }
end

factory :person, parent: :addressable, class: 'Person' do
  # ...
end

factory :company, parent: :addressable, class: 'Company' do
  # ...
end
```

P.S.
Seems like factory bot [got support for several parents](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/issues/132), so it might be possible to do several concerns support